# netty channel.iswritable() returns false, when concurrent level is high

Tags: java, netty

here is my code example, as I said in the title, when the concurrent level is high, isWritable() returns much false.

```
if (channel.isWritable()) {
        ChannelFuture future = channel.writeAndFlush(data);
        if (future.cause() != null) {
            data.release();
            throw new IOException(future.cause().toString());
        }
        future.addListener(writeCallback);
    }
```

And I wish someone can explain why this happens cause as far as I know, It happened when  I wrote but not flushed it so the buffer size add to more than the WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK size. But As you can see, I use writeAndFlush(), so I don't understand where is wrong?

Can this happened when cpu is too busy that it writes too many messages before it flushs the buffer?

Hope someone can help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is stated in `writeAndFlush(Object msg)` javadoc: `Shortcut for call write(Object) and flush().`, namely, it's just a syntactic sugar.

It means this is **not** an **atomic** operation, therefore there (possibly) are context switches between multiple threads in the middle of this method execution, so your writes are not flushed immediately, and therefore the channel's buffer gets fulled.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!